# android - when exactly to react to configuration change

Tags: android, configuration

Let's say the user has entered a text which I want to save and then re-insert when the screen has been rotated. Is onConfigurationChanged() called BEFORE the activity is destroyed so I can save the text in this method and set it in onRestart() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onSaveInstanceState()` method to save the values you want and then after screen orientation you can use `savedInstance` parameter passed to `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)`.
If you are handling configuration changes yourself i.e overriding `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` method then `onCreate` will not be called then you can use `onRestoreInstanceState()` as suggested.